# VisualSVN Server Hooks fails to send email

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have VisualSVN installed on remote machine and I have implement the post commit hook so that I can get the every email on check-in by any developer in team. My hook is:

```
"%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\VisualSVNServerHooks.exe" ^
commit-notification "%1" -r %2 ^
--from svn.admin --to <recepient mail> ^
--smtp-server <smtp server address>
```

Now after implementing it on remote machine(client domain), I am getting the below error on committing:

> VisualSVNServerHooks: E020014: The server rejected one or more
>   recipient addresses. The server response was: 550 5.7.1 ... Relaying
>   denied. IP name lookup failed

Comment: Ask **own postmaster** about this problem, not SO-users

Comment: I didn't get this. SO-users ???

Comment: @R.Sha The question has nothing to do with Subversion, VisualSVN Server or TortoiseSVN. Just take a closer look at the error and ask your sysadmin who is responsible for the SMTP server. FYI: SO means StackOverflow.